# offline mirror with aptly local storage not configured

Tags: 20.04, mirrors

I am using Aptly to publish a copy of ubuntu (main) repo to a USB stick for an offline machine.
(Using this video for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rZsJZ_1vX3o)

However when I try to publish the snapshot using this:

```
sudo aptly publish snapshot -skip-contents -skip-signing ubuntu_amd64 filesystem:packages:ubuntu-amd64
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: published local storage packages not configured
```

My .aptly.conf looks like this:

```
{
  "rootDir": "$HOME/.aptly",
  "downloadConcurrency": 16,
  "downloadSpeedLimit": 0,
  "architectures": ["amd64"],
  "dependencyFollowSuggests": false,
  "dependencyFollowRecommends": false,
  "dependencyFollowAllVariants": false,
  "dependencyFollowSource": false,
  "dependencyVerboseResolve": false,
  "gpgDisableSign": true,
  "gpgDisableVerify": true,
  "gpgProvider": "gpg",
  "downloadSourcePackages": false,
  "skipLegacyPool": true,
  "ppaDistributorID": "ubuntu",
  "ppaCodename": "",
  "skipContentsPublishing": false,
  "FileSystemPublishEndpoints": {
    "packages": {
      "rootDir": "/repo/public/packages",
      "linkMethod": "hardlink"
    }
},
  "S3PublishEndpoints": {},
  "SwiftPublishEndpoints": {}
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you have tried yourself. Just in case you haven't tried these, here are some suggestions of what to check: - Make sure that the path (/repo/public/packages) exists **and** has the necessary permissions. - Verify that filesystem:packages:ubuntu-amd64 is correctly referencing the defined endpoint in your .aptly.conf. - Make sure the reference to the local storage in your publish command (filesystem:packages:ubuntu-amd64) matches the endpoint configuration in your config file.